# Unexpected crash on macOS while overriding function return address

Tags: c, macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I was writing a program which takes many arguments as input parameters. I decided to copy all of them which were passed through registers to stack. To make iteration more consistent I decided to keep function return address in one of registers which wasn't used at time. Whenever I was overriding return address program crashed. Below you can find small piece of code which illustrates the problem. What is the cause? Is return address protected in any way?

```
section .text
  global _function

_function:
    mov rdx, rsp ; save return address
    mov rsp, 2   ; override return address, crashes here (segfault)
    mov rsp, rdx ; restore address
    ret
```

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int function (int n, ...);

int main() {
    printf("%d", function(7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2));
}
```

Comment: `rsp` *points to* the return address on the stack.  It isn't the return address itself.  But anyway, there's no reason that code should crash unless a signal handler happens to run while you have a non-pointer in RSP.  Is that example really *complete*?  [mcve]  Anything that uses the stack after you use RSP as a scratch register will segfault, but you haven't included any.  And `mov rsp, imm32` itself definitely won't crash.

Comment: Yes, it is complete. I provided as minimal example as it is possible when I realised strange problem occurs. This code compiles, runs and crashes on my computer. I have added C program as well

Comment: When you run it under `gdb` or `llvm-db`, what exactly do you see when it crashes?  Is RIP actually pointing to that `mov rsp,2`?  Or is it pointing to some later instruction?  And `_function` doesn't crash when it's just `ret`, or if you take out the `mov rsp,2` and leave the other instructions?  That would rule out anything else being the cause.  You did assemble this with `nasm -f macho64`, right?

Comment: `mov rsp, 2` is an instruction to move the contents of memory starting at the address 2 into rsp. Your process likely does not have read access to the memory at that address, so it crashes. You would want to move the immediate value 2 into `rsp`. In some assemblers, this is written as `$2`. Nonetheless, this is not what you want to do. use rsp only for pointing to the current top of stack. Decrease it to make more room on the stack, increase it to remove things from the stack. There are plenty of other registers available for general purpose use.

Comment: Program was compiled in 64-bit with debug flag. I invalided all cashes in clion, recompiled it and now it works perfectly fine. I have no idea what is going on. It rather seems to be problem with IDE than nasm itself. It looks as if the program was missing `ret` instruction even though it had one

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Given that the syntax appears to be NASM, `mov rsp, 2` would move the value 2 to _RSP_. In AT&T syntax you'd be correct, but the assembly directive `section .text` suggests this is Intel syntax and likely NASM. After I wrote this comment, OP confirmed that with his edit.

Comment: I should point out that `mov rdx, rsp` moves the stack pointer to _RDX_, To move the return address into _RDX_ you'd use `mov rdx, [rsp]` and the reverse would be `mov [rsp], rdx`

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?  It is pretty clear that this must crash; basically you set the stack pointer to 2, an address that is not mapped.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That would be true if this was GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`, but from the assembler directives we can tell this is NASM.  (It can't be AT&T syntax like Michael Petch suggested, though.  And `mov %rsp, 2` in AT&T syntax would be a store, not a load.)

Comment: @fuz: but the code doesn't use RSP as a pointer before restoring it.  It's rarely useful (and almost *never* a good idea) to use RSP as a scratch register, but it won't actually crash in user-space if you don't do any stack operations before restoring it and there isn't any asynchronous stack usage.  (i.e. no POSIX signal handlers installed.  So you can't safely use this from a library, or in any executable that calls library functions that might set up signal handlers.)

Comment: Couple of hours ago when I posted the question it wasn't matter if I modified rsp register or return address itself, result was the same - crash. I just wanted to simply example. It's a nasm syntax and as I explained the problem probably was caused by something else. I have no idea how it happened.

Comment: Okay, then I'm not sure what the problem is.